# Added data from CSV File to Java Derby Database deletes after closing the window

Tags: java, sql, javafx, derby

I have made a code to enable the user to upload a CSV file and add it to a derby database in Intellij. It works, but when the window is closed the data is gone. I'm using JavaFX and Java.

That's the method in the adapter class.

```java
//update the table with new csv file
public void editData(File path)throws SQLException {
    String line = "";
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //storing the csv file values in an array and removing all the commas that are existing in the file
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            //for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                // stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE am60Data SET Temperature ='" + values[0].toString() + "',Strain =  '" + values[1].toString() + "', Stress = '" + values[2].toString() + "', True_Strain = '" + values[3].toString() + "',True_Stress = '" + values[4].toString() + "' , " +
                //  "StrainRate = '" + values[4].toString() + "', Aloy_id = '" + values[4].toString() + "'   ");

            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO am60Data (Temperature,Strain,Stress,True_Strain,True_Stress,StrainRate,Aloy_id   ) " +
                         "VALUES('" + values[0].toString() + "', '" + values[1].toString() + "', '" + values[2].toString() + "',  '" + values[3].toString() + "', '" + values[4].toString() + "','" + values[4].toString() + "','" + values[4].toString() + "' )");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//method to edit the publishing unit

That's the method in the controller that's connected to my FXML file.

```
public void save()
{
    try {
        AM60adapter= new AM60Adapter(conn, true);
        AM60adapter.editData(new File(filePath.getText()));
        buildData();
        AM60adapter.getDataValues();

        // NOTE: This value is specific for Java DB
        String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:MeridianDB;create=true";
        // Create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        AM60adapter = new AM60Adapter(conn, true);
        compositionAdapter = new AM60CompositionAdapter(conn, true );
        summaryAdapter = new AM60SummaryAdapter(conn, true);
        creepAdapter = new AM60CreepAdapter(conn, true);

        //when the user clicks on the cancel button

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        displayAlert("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

All the inserted data disappears after closing the window. Please anyone help!

Comment: I don't know about derby but, do you have to commit the entries? Or is there an auto-commit for derby?

Comment: Side note: Don't use string concatenation to construct your queries like that; use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders and then call the appropariate `setXXX` methods.

Comment: this looks unrelated to javafx: get your derby code working as expected first, then try to apply in a fx context

Comment: Are you certain this is your actual code? Where is the variable `connection` coming from in the `editData` method and how is it related to the variable `conn` in the save() method? Also, how do you know the data is gone?